# Possibility of running an already running process into some other running process' memory

Tags: c, operating-system, exec

Can a currently running process (say `prcssA`) be dragged & run into another running process' (say `prcssB`) memory?

I was thinking something like the *PID* of the `prcssA` could be passed to a function (similar to a program's executable name passed to `exec` as an argument) called in `prcssB` & then the memory of `prcssA` could be copied into that of `prcssB` and then memory of `prcssA` could be freed.

> asked just for curiosity

Comment: sounds like to me you're blurring the lines of what distinguishes a process. Any modern OS is going to run each process in its own sandbox where they're not allowed to touch each other's memory. If you "load" prcssA into prcssB (exactly what this means would need to be ironed out), then I'd argue that's all part of prcssB and prcssA doesn't exist.

Comment: Do you mean if a thread in a process can migrate to other process?

Comment: You should clarify if you are asking about the whole adress space or just some parts. For the former the answer is no, it's generally not possible. For the latter the answer is yes.

Comment: @Nolan I have mentioned `prcssA`  to run into `prcssB` similar to how `exec` works - that means entire address space to be copied.

Comment: @tstanisl No, I mean entire process to migrate.

Comment: @yano yes it would violate that principle, but is it possible to do it somehow?

Comment: @Yano `prcssA` won't continue in it's original memory space, it will overtake `prcssB`'s memory and processing.

Comment: Try *man fork* and see if it close to what you want.

Comment: @mevets `fork` doesn't run other process in it's caller process' memory space, `exec` does.

Comment: No, exec replaces the imagine within a process; fork creates a new one.  If you search around for "unexec emacs"; you will find that it would fork a copy of itself; they child would cause a SIGSEGV, which generates a core file, then the library would re-write the core field to a valid executable, then *exec* it.   Voila; rewrote the address space.